# Suppress output of library configuration in cdt

Tags: c++, eclipse, ide, eclipse-cdt

In Eclipse CDT there used to be (version 3.7) a page in the properties called C/C++ General->Export Settings. It allowed you to control what was exported from the configuration (include folders, symbols and libraries after the build). Some of this functionality is still available in C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols.

It used to be possible to create a configuration that exported folders and symbols but didn't export a library by using this dialog page to remove the library from export list. Is there a way of reproducing this behavior now that the dialog page has gone?

(context: I have a configuration which just exports the headers for a library (and not the library itself) so I can create a dependency to that and have the headers that I need in other projects)